# How to get the most frequent value per group with number of occurrences in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

| store_id | time_range |
| --- | --- |
| 37 | 14-15 |
| 51 | 13-14 |
| 64 | 00-01 |
| 73 | 02-03 |
| 37 | 13-14 |
| ... | ... |

and I would like the output to be:

| store_id | time_range | max_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 37 | 14-15 | 5 |
| 51 | 13-14 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |

where `time_range` in the bottom table is the highest count per `store_id` and the `max_count` is the value which `time_range` was counted. The `store_id` must be unique

Currently, I have this code:

```
SELECT store_id, time_range, COUNT(store_id) 
FROM `sales_by_store_item_hour`  GROUP BY store_id
HAVING COUNT (store_id)=( 
SELECT MAX(time_range)
FROM ( 
SELECT store_id, COUNT(store_id) time_range
FROM `sales_by_store_item_hour` 
GROUP BY store_id));
```

but I still do not have any output.

pls helppp.

Comment: your data sample is not clear ..

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under this tag. Nevertheless, if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg):

```
SELECT 
  store_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(time_range, cnt) ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT store_id, time_range, COUNT(store_id) as cnt
  FROM `sales_by_store_item_hour`
  GROUP BY store_id, time_range
)
GROUP BY store_id
```